# Mapping to Multiple Classes in Restkit

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, restkit

I am using RestKit to map data to properties in two classes, Region and Category, for use in two table views, Regions and Categories.  However, it would appear that it is only correctly mapping data for the first view that I go to when testing the application.  For instance, when I view Categories first, then switch the Regions, my regions are getting stored as objects of type Category.  If I view Regions first, then Categories, my categories get mapped as objects of type Region.  I can tell that the right information is being retrieved, due the number of objects, but it is not being stored as the correct type.  How can I make sure that each mapping request is done correctly?  The code for each mapping is below:

Categories:

```
RKURL *baseURL = [RKURL URLWithBaseURLString:@"MyUrl"];
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:baseURL];
objectManager.client.baseURL = baseURL;

RKObjectMapping *categoryMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Category class]];
[categoryMapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:@"categoryID", @"categoryID", @"parentID", @"parentID", @"categoryName", @"categoryName", @"childrenCount", @"childrenCount", @"parentCount", @"parentCount", @"catCount", @"catCount", nil];
[objectManager.mappingProvider setMapping:categoryMapping forKeyPath:@""];
```

Regions:

```
RKURL *baseURL = [RKURL URLWithBaseURLString:@"MyUrl"];
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:baseURL];
objectManager.client.baseURL = baseURL;

NSLog(@"URL Created");

RKObjectMapping *regionMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Region class]];
[regionMapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:@"regionHome", @"regionHome", @"regionID", @"regionID", @"regionName", @"regionName", @"parentCount", @"parentCount", @"parentID", @"parentID", @"childrenCount", @"childrenCount", @"parentName", @"parentName", nil];
[objectManager.mappingProvider setMapping:regionMapping forKeyPath:@""];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my judgment you don't want to leave the key path as `@""` in `[objectManager.mappingProvider setMapping:regionMapping forKeyPath:@""];`.  You will probably replace those with `@"region"` and `@"category"` so RestKit can tell based on the key path what objects it should expect.

Also, are you using the `isKindOfClass:` method to distinguish the objects in the objectLoader `didLoadObjects` method?

Perhaps this will help you:

```
- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)objectLoader didLoadObjects:(NSArray*)objects {

  if ([[objects objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[Region class]]) {

      Region *region = [objects objectAtIndex:0];

  }
  else if ([[objects objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[Category class]]) {

      Category *category = [objects objectAtIndex:0];

  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I will talk to the developer who is working on the web service to see about modifying the key paths.  I added the isKindOfClass method, as suggested, and that does prevent the program from crashing, but the second table is now simply empty.  It is as if my second mapping request is simply not called.  I have tried using removeMappingForKeyPath, but that hasn't worked either.

Comment: What is an example of a URL you are hitting for the RestKit calls?

Comment: I am hosting the web service locally, so I am using my IP address and a port for the URL.  It looks like "http://[IP Address]:[Port]".

Comment: That's the base URL, but what's the actual path for a call? Something like "http://[IP Address]/myapp/api/category".  In this case "/myapp/api/category" would be the resource path, not "".

Comment: I specify the resource path with "objectManager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/api/Main/Process"".  I then use headers to direct the call to the appropriate function, such as "getCategories" or "getRegions".  Does it have something to do with both Regions and Categories having an empty key path?